# echarts4r highlight line series on mouseover

Tags: r, data-visualization

Using echarts4r package for R, is there a way to highlight a line series in a multi line chart by mouseover?  For example, in the pie chart [here](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-examples/public/editor.html?c=pie-simple) moving the mouse over the pie segments makes them larger.  For a line chart is it possible to fade the other series on mouseover?

Here is the example chart in R:

```
mtcars %>% e_charts(mpg) %>% e_title("MTCARS", "Test chart") %>% 
    e_line(drat) %>% e_line(wt) %>% e_datazoom(type = "slider") %>% 
    e_tooltip(trigger = "axis") %>% e_toolbox()
```

In this case, moving the mouse over the `drat` series on the chart would highlight it while fading the `wt` series.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, sadly the line itself cannot be emphasised, see [this issue](https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/issues/2675). However you can customize the  emphasised point(s).

```
style <- list(
    itemStyle = list(
        color = "blue",
        opacity = .5
    )
)

mtcars %>% e_charts(mpg) %>% 
    e_title("MTCARS", "Test chart") %>% 
    e_line(drat, emphasis = style) %>% 
    e_line(wt, emphasis = style) %>% 
    e_datazoom(type = "slider") %>% 
    e_tooltip(trigger = "axis") %>% 
    e_toolbox() %>%
    e_toolbox_feature("saveAsImage")
```

More options for the line on the [official JavaScript documentation](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#series-lines)

Comment: This is sad - however if useful I discovered how to change the toolbox feature to be English `e_toolbox_feature("saveAsImage", title="Save Image")`